# integral inequality of a non-increasing function on [0,1]...

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality

I'm trying to prove an inequality from one of my real analysis books, and struggling. The problem is as follows:
Show that for any non-increasing f: that maps [0,1] to the reals, and any θ in (0,1) we have the following inequality:
$\displaystyle θ\int_{0 }^{1}f(x)dx$ $\leq$ $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{θ}f(x)dx$

I've tried to approach this similar to a previously asked question about the specific case where θ=1/2, however I haven't gotten far with that method. The other consideration I had was using a max to show that one integral had to be less than or equal to f at a certain point times the difference in x values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $\theta\in(0,1)$ and $f$ is non increasing $$\theta x\leq x\implies f(x)\leq f(\theta x)\implies \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \;dx\leq\int_{0}^{1} f(\theta x)\;dx$$

Make the change of variable $t=\theta x$ in the second integral, and you get:

$$\int_{0}^{\theta}f(t) \frac{dt}{\theta}$$, so

$$\int_{0}^{1} f(t) \;dt\leq\int_{0}^{\theta} f(t)\;\frac{dt}{\theta}\implies\theta\int_{0}^{1} f(t) \;dt\leq\int_{0}^{\theta} f(t)\;dt$$
as we wanted.